# calculate amount of time intersection when all sequences fulfill certain criteria?

Tags: python, algorithm

I've been thinking hard for a long time but couldn't work this out. Consider the following sequences over time, which records the status of switches:

A = [(10:00, 1), (11:00, 0), (12:00, 1), (12:30, 0),..., (23:00, 1)] # switch A is on at 10:00, off at 11:00 and so on

B = [(10:30, 1), (11:15, 0), (11:30, 1), (12:15, 0),..., (23:30, 0)] # likewise

C = ...

(In reality the time is in the format of python's time.struct_time.)

So basically the structure would be [(time1, status1), (time2, status2)...]. The lists contains data within 24h, and only the switching instances are recorded (so the adjacent "status"es are always opposite to each other). I want to calculate the total amount of time, when all switches A,B,C are on. This seemingly simple question is taking me many days to come up with something useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First merge all lists into one list of tuples in the format `(time, switch, state)`. Then sort all the status switches by time, giving a timeline of events.

Then have three variables, `a_on`, `b_on` and `c_on`. Initialize them as the problem specifies (do they start all off or on, etc). Then do something like this:

```
last_time = 0 # starting time of data, 0 is here as example
total_time = 0 # 0 seconds

for time, switch, state in state_switches:
    if a_on and b_on and c_on:
        total_time += time - last_time

    if switch == "A":
        a_on = state
    if switch == "B":
        b_on = state
    if switch == "C":
        c_on = state

    last_time = time
```

Comment: but literally writing the condition "a_on and b_on and c_on" doesn't work as it doesn't necessarily fulfill even if a,b,c are all on, because the times stored are discrete.

Comment: ok i see your point here. i should have thought about this! thank you

Comment: You could simplify this by implementing a function that takes as input two switch timelines and returns a timeline. That way you could extend this function to work with any number of switches.

Answer (score 0):

How about representing the times a switch is enabled as a list of minutes of the day when a switch is enabled, e.g. `A=[600, 601, 602, ..., 659, ..., ]`, where 10am corresponds to minute 600 in the day.  Convert the lists to sets and use a sum of the intersections.